# Need to run migration console app: Too many records killing process - no idea how to solve

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, transactions, unit-of-work

I've written a bit of code to manipulate data for a comprehensive transaction. However, am suffering endless problems and dead ends. If I run my code on a small data set, it works as expected. But now that I've had the production environment restored to the testing db, to get a full scope of testing. I basically wasted my time as best I can tell.

```
private static void AddProvisionsForEachSupplement2(ISupplementCoordinator supplmentCord)
    {


        var time = DateTime.Now;
        using (var scope = new UnitOfWorkScope())
        {
            var supplements = supplmentCord.GetContracts(x => x.EffectiveDate <= new DateTime(2014, 2, 27)).AsEnumerable();

            foreach (var supplement in supplements){

                    var specialProvisionTable = supplement.TrackedTables.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "SpecialProvisions");


                    SetDefaultSpecialProvisions(specialProvisionTable, supplement);


                    Console.Out.WriteLine(supplement.Id.ToString() + ": " + (DateTime.Now - time).TotalSeconds);

            }

        }
    }
```

You can see I decided to test my timing, it takes roughly 300+ seconds to complete the loop, and then the 'commit' that occurs is obscenely long. Probably longer.

I get this error:

```
The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.
```

I added [Transaction(Timeout = 6000)] to even get that, before I was getting a transaction timeout.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much more info that we need and giving you a definitive answer is going to be tough. However when dealing with large datasets in one massive transaction is always going to hurt performance.

However, the first thing I would do too be honest is to hook up a SQL profiler (like [NHProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof), or SQL profiler, or even [Log4Net](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx)) to see how many queries you are issuing. Then as you test you can see if you can reduce the queries which will in turn reduce the time.

Then after working this out you have a few options:-

1. Use a stateless session to grab data, but this removes change tracking so you will need to persist it later manually
2. Reduce the single big transactions into smaller transactions  (**this is what I would start with**)
3. See if eager loading a whole lot of data in one hit might be more efficient
4. See if using [batching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576609/nhibernate-batch-size-doesnt-work) is going to help you

Don't give up, fight and understand why this is giving you issues, this is the key becoming a master of NHibernate (rather than a slave to it)

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks Rippo, I was trying to be concise. I'll add sme more information, though I'd place it as a mid range 6 figure number of queries. I can't really cut it down any more than I have without rewriting the entire backend of a project that is 'dev complete' this is for a retroactive db update. It'd take a masters thesis to demonstrate how much garbage in in this project, so I was hoping that indicating waaaay too big and a transaction timeout would lead to the same answer if it were 100k queries or 600k queries.